# Помогите с оптимизацией кода для Arduino, цель уменьшение использования памяти

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, arduino

При реализации умного дома, я использую связку устройств на базе ESP8266 в а частности WemosD1 mini, для управления Rele по средством публикации данных в MQTT брокера [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/download/). И моя реализация кода для данного вида устройств работает идеально, в связи с достаточным количеством памяти у них.

Но завалялась у меня без дела Arduino Leonardo и ENC28J60 (аналог Ethernet Shild) для организации связки библиотеки [PubSubClient.h](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) с ENC28J60 подходит только полный аналог стандартной библиотеки Ethernet.h , а именно [UIPEthernet.h](https://github.com/ntruchsess/arduino_uip)

Код скетча весьма большой и если можно я приведу ссылку [Ссылка на код](https://github.com/leganas/SmartHome-Arduino/blob/master/mqtt_object_leonardo_ethernet/mqtt_object_leonardo_ethernet.ino)

Я использую ООП подход и облегчённую реализацию Vector из библиотеки [Arduino_Vector](https://github.com/zacsketches/Arduino_Vector) , и как показала практика это ни сколько не увеличивает количество занимаемой памяти в итоге, но при этом значительно унифицирует код.

Однако сами библиотеки для работы с LAN и MQTT , весьма объёмны и по факту на Arduino Leonardo  я не могу добавить в свой список больше 3х устройств , Arduino переглючивает и перестаёт выполнять свои функции.

Используя рекомендации из статьи [статьи](https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2017/01/14/mqtt-with-the-enc8266/) я пробовал отключить UDP протокол, тем самым сэкономить 5кб памяти, но при такой конфигурации у меня перестаёт подключатся к MQQT брокеру.

Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать C++ код , возможно в частях работы со строками для уменьшения количества используемой памяти.

Comment: Упс, там компилятор все оптимизирует, имхо, в с++ оптимизация весьма условная, основное место и память жрет stl

Comment: Ваша программа должна страдать не только с точки зрения используемой памяти, но и с точки зрения скорости.  Я не углублялся в детальях, но с первого взгляда архитектура  не понравилась.

Comment: скорости чего ?

Comment: на этой железячке всего то 2.5 кб памяти. А Вы для поля Device.state используете целый int (который два  байта, а там похоже одного бита хватит). DeviceType наверно также в int превратился. Поэтому, весь Device занимает минимум 10 байт,  а мог бы 3-4. И так далее...

Answer (score 1):

Нужно как можно больше данных инкапсулировать в одном обьекте.  Для примера я укажу на кусочек вашего кода:

```
byte ip[] = {192, 168, 88, 120}; // IP-адрес
byte myDns[] = {192, 168, 88, 1}; // адрес DNS-сервера
byte gateway[] = {192, 168, 88, 1}; // адрес сетевого шлюза
byte subnet[] = {255, 255, 255, 0}; // маска подсети    
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.88.253";
const char* mqtt_login = "";
const char* mqtt_password = "";
```

вместо того, чтобы использовать так много памяти, можно написать класс хранящий эти данные и по мере необходимости, возвращающий их.

```
using  std::string;
using  std::vector;
class Data {
    vector<byte> v;
    vector<string> vs;
public:
    void addData(const char* p) { vs.emplace_back(p); }
    void addData(std::initializer_list<byte> b)
    { v.insert(v.end(), b); }

    byte ip(size_t i)  const    { return v[i % 4];}
    byte myDns(size_t i) const  { return v[4 + i%4]; }
    byte gateway(size_t i) const { return v[8 + i%4]; }
    byte subnet(size_t i) const { return v[12 + i%4]; }

    string mqtt_server() const { return vs[0]; }
    string mqtt_login() const { return vs.size() > 1 ? vs[1] : ""; }
    string  mqtt_password()  const{ return vs.size() > 2 ? vs[2] : ""; }
    size_t size_to_byte() const  { return v.size(); }
};
```

а потом использовать обьект этого класса следующим образом (тут память нужна всего для одного обьекта):

```
int main()
{    
    Data data;
    data.addData({192, 168, 88, 120});
    data.addData({192, 168, 88, 1});
    data.addData({192, 168, 88, 1});
    data.addData({255, 255, 255, 0});    
    //проверка
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) {
        std::cout << data.ip(i) <<'\t';
        if (data.size_to_byte() >= 12)
            cout << data.subnet(i) << std::endl;
    }
    cout << sizeof(data); //память требуется более чем в 4 раза меньше    
    return 0;
}
```

Обращаю ваше внимание на то, что это всего лишь пример для наглядности, что можно  делать и как нужно строить программу. Класс можно написать иначе, можно все данные просто хранить в каком то удобном контейнере и  уже обращаться только к кускам этого контейнера.  А вообше лучше заного подумать о всей архитектуры программы.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ваши рекомендации, буду учитывать, но по факту обошёлся малой кровью
модифицировал 1 функцию

```
 const String catStr(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
  char result[50];
  snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%s%s", str1, str2);
  return String (result);
}
```

просто уменьшил размер буфера для конкатенации строк